# How can I access a MySQL View from Coldfusion ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I am trying (first time) to query a MySQL View from a Coldfusion HQL. I get the Log-Message: "vwName is not mapped". Does anybody know, if this is possible and how I can achieve that.
Regards.

Comment: I have defined a View in MySQL, which is working (since showing all requested rows). Now I would like to access this view from a Coldfusion Component (connected through a Flex Application). Trying to access the view gives me the error: ......"vwName not mapped".... What do I have to define in Coldfusion, getting access to that view ?

Comment: Show us the code where you are trying to access the view.

Comment: Are you referring to the view or an entity with the name "VwName"?

Comment: Any query that ORM generates will work on the views in the same way as it does on a table. So while defining the persistence metadata for your CFC, just use the view name instead of the table name and you should be all set.